# Filling a html form with cURL and pressing the Set button

Tags: html, forms, curl

I am trying to fill html fields from the command line using cURL.
The html-code of the page I am trying to modify is this:

```html
<tr>
<td width="27%" class="vncellt">Device's Name</td>
<td width="73%" class="vcell">
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/cfgsvr">
<input id="SA_svrname" size="40" maxlength="40"/>
<input type="text" style="display:none"/>
<input type="button" class="formbtn" value="Set" onclick="makeRequest(form1)"/>ev
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried numerous variations of this:
curl --form "SA_svrname=roflkopter&press=Set" http://10.1.100.190/sysinfo.html
to no avail...
What am  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post to the same page that the form is posting to?

```
curl --data "SA_svrname=roflkopter&press=Set" http://10.1.100.190/cfgsvr
```

I believe the form from you example is missing the name parameters for the input fields however

Comment: I have tried that - won't work either.
So my actual problem is the missing name for the button?

Comment: Could the problem be with whatever file handles the request that goes to /cfgsvr ? Perhaps you can echo the post array there to see what you are receiving and what the result is.